# Launching activity with animation Service

Tags: java, android, animation, android-intent, service

I am looking for a way to launch an `activity/app` with animation from a service. For that I have tried several ways but they failed. I tried to use `overridePendingTransitions()` but that doesn't work in service.

So is there a way to launch activity/app intent with animation from service?

Comment: Is it necessary to provide animation from service ?

Answer (score 1):

on this DevByte http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA Chet Haase (one of the Android engineers working on the animation framework) shows some extras parameters that can be added to the intent starting from JellyBean only that would possibly work from a Service. I suggest giving it a try.

and here there's a class from the support library that helps on some of those stuff: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat.html

Comment: There is no method or techique shown for animating an app from a service

Comment: the methods shown are applying the animation to the intent, regardless  where u create it. I think it's worth giving a try.